# Lower bound of sequence to prove limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have to prove that limit of following sequence $a_n = \sqrt[n]{(\frac{2012}{2013})^n - (\frac{2011}{2012})^n}$ equals $\frac{2012}{2013}$. $a_n < \sqrt[n]{(\frac{2012}{2013})^n - 0} = \frac{2012}{2013}$ but we also need to find lower bound of $a_n$. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something more general: If $x > y > 0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{x^n - y^n} = x$. This is because
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{x^n - y^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x^n\big(1-(y/x)^n\big)}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} x\cdot\sqrt[n]{1-(y/x)^n}=x\cdot\sqrt[n]{1-0}=x.
$$